# Splitting string by {0}, {1}...{n} and replace with empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have the following String:

```
var text = "Hello world! My name is {0}. How {1} can you be?"
```

I wanna find each of the {n} and replace them with an empty string. I'm totally useless with regex and tried this:

```
text = text.split("/^\{\d+\}$/").join("");
```

I'm sure this is an easy answer and probably exist some answer already on SO but I'm not sure what to search for. Not even sure what the "{" are called in english.

Please (if possible) maintain the use of "split" and "join".

Thanks!

Comment: You write regex'es in JavaScript like this: `/hello/flags` where hello is the match pattern. in your case: `text.split(/\{\d+\}/);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve this through `string.replace` function.

```
string.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, "")
```

Example:

```
> var text = "Hello world! My name is {0}. How {1} can you be?"
undefined
> text.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, "")
'Hello world! My name is . How  can you be?'
```

Through `string.split`. You just need to remove the anchors. `^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end. Because there isn't only a string `{num}` exists in a single line, your regex fails. And also remove the quotes which are around the regex delimiter `/`

```
> text.split(/\{\d+\}/).join("");
'Hello world! My name is . How  can you be?'
```

Comment: Thank you (and all others who were quick to answer), this worked just perfect! :)

Answer (score 5):

You were close.  What you want is:  `text = text.split(/\{\d+\}/).join("");`

The two things that you missed were:

1. `^` = the start of the string and `$` = the end of the string.  Since there are other characters around the pattern that you are trying to match, you don't want those.
2. if you are using a regular expression in the `split()` method, you need to use a `RegExp` object, not a string.  Removing the `"`'s and just having the expression start and end with `/` will define a RegExp object.

I would actually agree with the others that the `replace()` method would be a better way to do what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to use `split()` and `join()`, as you've stated, this is the change that you need.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for explaining my errors! RegEx is a mystery I will never be able to memorize (atleast it feels that way now). I will consider using replace instead!

Comment: Just keep practicing . . . it gets easier.   :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `replace` mehthod:

```
var repl = text.replace(/\{\d+\} */g, '');
//=> "Hello world! My name is . How can you be?"
```